# Recent commits disappear when I use git rebase?

Tags: git, github

I have the `main` and the `feature` branch:

on main: `git log --oneline`:

```
a00 merge pull request 18
b00 merge pull request 17
c00 refactored X class
```

On feature: `git log --oneline` (8 commits):

```
j44 deleted files
o64 renamed files
p22 merge branch `feature` from github.com/... into feature
x11 fixed duplicating bug
y88 refactor controller
a00 merge pull request 18 (-- this is the last commit on main, above this every commit happened on feature branch --)
b00 merge pull request 17
c00 refactored X class
```

When I run the `git rebase main` on the `feature` branch:

On feature `git log --oneline` (5 commits):

```
x11 fixed duplicating bug
y88 refactor controller
a00 merge pull request 18
b00 merge pull request 17
c00 refactored X class
```

So it rebases only until `p22 merge branch` commit. It forgots this 3 commits:

```
j44 deleted files
o64 renamed files
p22 merge branch `feature` from github.com/... into feature
```

Any way to fix this? I have no knowledge of the rebase, never had to use it before... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the option `--graph` to see a clearer picture.

Comment: Do not expect to see merge commits after a rebase, unless you use `--rebase-merges`.

Comment: check if rebase is paused due to conflicts